# Python - File Path not found if script run from another directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a script that works without issue when I run using in console, but causes issue if I try to run it from another directory (via IPython %run <script.py>)

The issue comes from this line, where it references a folder called "Pickles".

```
 with open('Pickles/'+name+'_'+date.strftime('%y-%b-%d'),'rb') as f:
            obj = pickle.load(f)
```

In Console:

> python script.py  <---works!

In running IPython (Jupyter) in another folder, it causes a `FileNotFound` exception.

How can I make any path references within my scripts more robust, without putting the whole extended path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you expect Python to know where to look for the `Pickles` directory when you don't execute your script in the directory containing it?  If you run your script from another folder, your code is going to expect `Pickles` to be in that directory. How would you like your code to find that directory?  Is there something else that you want your code to use to determine where that directory is, like maybe the location of the script?

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since running in the console the way you show works, the `Pickles` directory must be in the same directory as the script. You can make use of this fact so that you don't have to hard code the location of the `Pickles` directory, but also don't have to worry about setting the "current working directory" to be the directory containing `Pickles`, which is what your current code requires you to do.

Here's how to make your code work no matter where you run it from:

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Pickles', name + '_' + date.strftime('%y-%b-%d')), 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` provides the path to the directory containing the script that is currently running.

Generally speaking, it's a good practice to always fully specify the locations of things you interact with in the filesystem.  A common way to do this as shown here.

UPDATE: I updated my answer to be more correct by not assuming a specific path separator character.  I had chosen to use '/' only because the original code in the question already did this.  It is also the case that the code given in the original question, and the code I gave originally, will work fine on Windows.  The `open()` function will accept either type of path separator and will do the right thing on Windows.

Comment: the character "/" is not cross platform (no windows friendly) uses `os.sep` or `os.path.join` insteed!

Comment: The code in question already contained a '/'.  I was just following the existing convention used by the code.  The value of this answer is not reduced by the fact that that it is not handling paths in a platform-neutral way.  The initial code already wasn't doing that.  .... but sure, I'll change it....

Comment: @VincentBénet - What you say in your comment is technically incorrect.  While it is better form to use `os.path.join`, the code I gave in my answer will work fine on Windows.  The `open()` function will deal with converting the path that is given to a valid Windows path.  There are a bunch of drive letter things it does as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use absolute paths. Also to be cross platform use `join`:

- First get the path of your script using the variable `__file__`
- Get the directory of this file with `os.path.dirname(__file__)`
- Get your relative path with `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Pickles", f"{name}_{date.strftime('%y-%b-%d')}")`

it gives you:

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Pickles", f"{name}_{date.strftime('%y-%b-%d')}"), 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```